# Relist adjective when I want to say both are that quality?

Tags: adjectives

If I want to say that I like good music and good movies, which do I say:

1. I love good movies and music.
2. I love good movies and good music.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say either: they mean the same.

The first one *could* be ambiguous, meaning "good movies and all music", but I doubt if anybody would take it that way, unless you put particular emphasis.